# How can I debug a .exe from the command line with a .exe generated from cl.exe (Visual Studio C/C++ Compiler)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How can I debug a .exe from the command line with a .exe generated from cl.exe (Visual Studio C/C++ Compiler)?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-using-cdb-and-ntsd

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't going to use a proper debugger (such as found with the full version of visual studio or windbg.exe) then your best bet will be old fashioned printed log traces. Add code (when usingh cl.exe usually bracketed by #ifdef _DEBUG/#endif directives) that print messages to the console about your current program state. Using a real debugger is, however, generally much easier.

Comment: I don't like using the Visual Studio editor so I would like to use Sublime Text. It would be nice if there was a way to get the information displayed in the "Call Stack" panel in Visual Studio which provides the line number that the runtime error occurred from the command line. I'm used to being able to debug from the command line like with Node.js which I like much better, but it seems like when developing C/C++ on Windows you are locked into using Visual Studio and their editor, the bunch of project files it generates, and that whole setup to code/compile/debug.

Comment: @paradigm111 Not really, you don't have to use Visual Studio. Visual Studio just gives you an easy setup for people less familiar with command line and config files. Here's a link for setting up [VSCode with debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug), and I would suspect it's that different from using Sublime